# Host's pods panel in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, promql

I want to have a panel in Grafana which displays what pods are currently running in a host.
For the host variable I have the following query (the job variable is just `label_values(node_uname_info, job)`.):

```
label_values(node_uname_info{job="$job"}, instance)
```

This gives me an array of sockets: host_ip:port

I can get the pod names from `kube_pod_info{job="$job", host_ip="$host_ip"}`, but in order to get the IP I need to remove the port part of the socket:

```
label_replace(node_uname_info{job="$job", instance="$node"}, "host_ip", "$1", "instance", "(.*):.*")
```

I haven't found how to use the new `host_ip` label in the pod query to eventually get all the pod label values of `kube_pod_info`. I don't want to put the `label_replace` in Prometheus to avoid data duplication - is there a way to use the new `host_ip` label in the pod query?

*Edit*:

I added the `host_ip` variable with the regex as shan1024 showed in his answer and changed the panel's query to:

```
sum by (pod) (kube_pod_info{job="$job", host_ip="$host_ip"})
```

Then I changed the panel's visualization to table and added column styles to `Time` and `Value` (chose type Hidden). This allows me to display the host's running pods in a list-like fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do in Grafana and no need to change labels in Prometheus. You just need to add a regex in the **instance** variable (when we add a regex with a capturing group, the value(s) of the 1st captured group will be the value(s) of the variable).

e.g.

Variable definition without Regex (you get **host_ip:port**)-

[image]

Variable definition with Regex (you only get **host_ip**)-

[image]

Then you can add a new variable with value `kube_pod_info{ host_ip="$instance" }` to get all pods in the selected host.